# Semantic Application Logging Block - Console logging in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using **Semantic Logging Application Block** in our asp.net c# application. I am developing using Visual Studio 2013. I have created a listener which logs to a flat file and this works fine.

But I cannot get [Console.LogToConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.semanticlogging.consolelog.logtoconsole%28v=pandp.60%29.aspx) to work. i.e., I don't see the log message in the Visual Studio Output window. I have checked the Immediate window and the log messages are not visible there either. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad it's not just me. I'm going mad trying to get a simple console logger going. I've followed the MSDN guide and other articles, but no joy. I've got my custom EventSource class and am creating the listener in the Application_Start() method and the WriteEvent() calls work, but there's no output! Argh!

Comment: Are you using `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing` instead of `System.Diagnostics.Tracing`? That breaks Console logging for me.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party but you can create a custom event listener that writes to whatever you prefer (in this case Debug) like so:

```
    internal class MyEventListener : EventListener
    {
        protected override void OnEventSourceCreated(EventSource eventSource)
        {
            base.OnEventSourceCreated(eventSource);

            Debug.WriteLine("Listener attached to the source");
        }

        protected override void OnEventWritten(EventWrittenEventArgs eventData)
        {
            ICollection readOnlyCollectionObject = (ICollection)eventData.Payload;
            object[] payload = new ArrayList(readOnlyCollectionObject).ToArray();

            Debug.WriteLine(eventData.Message, payload);
        }
    }
```

And then, with our custom event listener built, we simply fire it up in the normal fashion:

```
var listener = new MyEventListener();
listener.EnableEvents(MyEventSource.Log, EventLevel.Informational);

MyEventSource.Log.MyEvent("Hello from the Immediate window!");
```

Credit to: http://www.shujaat.net/2013/08/slab-reactive-event-sourcing.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing as I first started with visual studio. Console.LogToConsole does what it says, logs to the console in a console app. Neither the Output nor Immediate windows are the console. The console looks like a DOS window. You wouldn't see this running an ASP.Net site. You would have to specifically create a console application. One note to mention, if you're debugging or running a console app within visual studio, sometimes the console window would be behind visual studio. Look for the icon that pops up in your windows task bar. Hope this helps!